# Questions about a fossil

Tags: botany, species-identification

I have a plant fossil that my dad once found for me at a beach in Denmark, Europe about 15 years ago.

- Is it possible to identify what kind of plant it is? There is a fossil water bubble suggesting that this plant lived under water.
- What kind of process did the plant undergo in order to become a fossil?
- Is it possible to find out how old it is?

[image]

Comment: Carbon dating could tell you how old it is...

Comment: Knowing what layer it came from you can infer when it was formed.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not a fossil, but a [pseudofossil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudofossil): a pretty deposit of iron or manganese called a [dendrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrite_(crystal)).

Comment: That is interesting.. +1